# textFont() not working in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

Alright, I'm just trying to add this font to my website, but this error keeps showing up in the console.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Substitution.getDefaultScriptName (p5.js:31993)
at Font.stringToGlyphs (p5.js:27954)
at Font.forEachGlyph (p5.js:28069)
at Font.getAdvanceWidth (p5.js:28144)
at p5.Font._textWidth (p5.js:63498)
at p5.Font._handleAlignment (p5.js:63523)
at p5.Font._getPath (p5.js:63339)
at p5.Font._renderPath (p5.js:63458)
at p5.Renderer2D._renderText (p5.js:48828)
at p5.Renderer2D.text (p5.js:48788)
```

This is the only error that appears and it makes my entire code stop.

Here is my code:

```
var sound;
var imgs = [];
var myFont;
function preload() {
    soundFormats('mp3');
    sound = loadSound('Your Reality.mp3');
    myFont = loadFont('assets/monika.ttf');
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        imgs[i] = loadImage('assest/img(' + i + ').png');
    }
}
function setup() {
    imageMode(CENTER);
    sound.setVolume(0.5);
    sound.play();
    //sound.onended(soundEnd);
    createCanvas(windowWidth-20, windowHeight-20);
    text("Click Anywhere!", 0, 10);
    soundEnd();
}
function soundEnd() {
    imgs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        imgs[i] = loadImage('assets/img(' + i + ').png');
    }
    reload();
    textSize(36);
    textFont(myFont);
    var inter = setInterval(flashText, 200);
}
function flashText() {
    text("Just Monika", floor(random(0, width-30)), floor(random(0, height-15)));
}
function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth - 20, windowHeight - 20);
}
function reload() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth - 20, windowHeight - 20);
    text("Click Anywhere!", 0, 10);
}
```

What is supposed to happen is that music plays, and you can click your mouse (mouseClicked function not included in this code because it was irrelevent) and some images will appear, after the music ends a different set of images will appear, then the text "Just Monika" is supposed to flash around the screen in a specific font,but the font isn't working, is this an issue with p5.js?

Comment: [It works for me](https://i.imgur.com/WxGCI14.png). Maybe the font is the issue? or could it be a CORS config issue?

Comment: That's really weird, it must be the font file? At any rate you made me realize how much I really don't like that font anyway so I'll try another one.

Comment: So weird! It was the file for some reason. Thanks!

Comment: No problem at all.